# Getting "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor" error when using Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensor

I am trying to implement a model in Keras and got the following error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Here is my model:

```
def create_base_network(input_shape, out_dims):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(out_dims, activation='linear'))

    return model

input_shape=(28,28,3)
anchor_in = Input(shape=input_shape)
pos_in = Input(shape=input_shape)
neg_in = Input(shape=input_shape)

base_network = create_base_network(input_shape, 128)
anchor_out = base_network(anchor_in)
pos_out = base_network(pos_in)
neg_out = base_network(neg_in)

merged = concatenate([anchor_out, pos_out, neg_out], axis=-1)

model = Model(inputs=[anchor_in, pos_in, neg_in], outputs=merged)
```

I then try to get the output from the sequential model using:

```
seq_fun = K.function([model.layers[0].input, model.layers[1].input, model.layers[2].input], [model.layers[3].get_output_at(0)])
seq_output = seq_fun([a, p, n])[0]
```

The input to this is coming from a generator in form of a numpy array each with the required shape. The error message then is:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,28,28,3]
 [[{{node conv2d_1_input}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,28,28,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
 [[{{node dense_2/BiasAdd/_175}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_102_dense_2/BiasAdd", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I don't really know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequential model you have created have 4 output nodes. The one with index zero, i.e. `get_output_at(0)`, is the result of feeding it directly and the other three are its outputs when it is fed using one of the input layers you have defined. Obviously the first one is not connected to the input layers you have defined, therefore you get the error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor ...

So you need to specify other three output nodes (index 1, 2 or 3) as the output of your custom function:

```
seq_fun = K.function([model.layers[0].input, model.layers[1].input, model.layers[2].input], 
                      [model.layers[3].get_output_at(i)])  # i must be 1, 2 or 3
```

As a side note, you can define the custom function more succinctly using `inputs` attribute of the model:

```
seq_fun = K.function(model.inputs, [model.layers[3].get_output_at(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

reinstall tensorflow==1.11.0 and keras==2.1.2 works for me.